# CK editor tool bar - underline button not showing up

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm using CK editor latest version (4.5). I have downloaded full package.
I have customized toolbar to include underline button, however it's not showing up! I have seen few people mention the default config.js has a line to remove underline button. I have already made sure that config.js isn't removing any button. Any ideas?

Here is my toolbar setting:

```
config.toolbar=[
['Sourcedialog']
['Undo','Redo','-','Find','Replace','-','RemoveFormat'],
['Image','Table','HorizontalRule','SpecialChar'],
['Link','Unlink','Anchor'],                 
['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
'/',
['Styles','Format','FontSize'],
['TextColor'], 
['Bold','Italic','Strike','Underline','-','Subscript','Superscript'], 
['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Blockquote'],     
['Maximize','-','ShowBlocks'],
];
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue. "u" was added into disallowed content list. So the underline button was not showing up!

Comment: So there is a solution for that ?